# How to draw a continuous line in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to draw a line when mouse clicked and moving in Pygame framework, it will be a line if I move the mouse very slowly. However, if I move the mouse quickly, it's just incontinuous dots. The question is how to draw a continuous line when mouse move? Thanks in advance.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
    pygame.init()

    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

    mouse_position = (0, 0)
    drawing = False
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 800), 0, 32)
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("ScratchBoard")

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                if (drawing):
                    mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, mouse_position, mouse_position, 1)
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mouse_position = (0, 0)
                drawing = False
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                drawing = True

        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It's still incontinuous after I correct the end position:             elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                if (drawing):
                    start_position = event.pos
                    end_position = (event.pos[0] + event.rel[0], event.pos[1] + event.rel[1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `pygame.draw.line` with the same argument (mouse_position) twice, you're not drawing a line, you're drawing a single pixel, because start_pos and end_pos are the same.

To get a contiguous line, you need to save the last position and draw a line between it and the next position, like this (changes are the lines with `last_pos`):

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
    pygame.init()

    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

    mouse_position = (0, 0)
    drawing = False
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 800), 0, 32)
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("ScratchBoard")

    last_pos = None

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                if (drawing):
                    mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if last_pos is not None:
                        pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, last_pos, mouse_position, 1)
                    last_pos = mouse_position
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mouse_position = (0, 0)
                drawing = False
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                drawing = True

        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you want to make _one_ continuous line, this code works good. If you want the line to break and stay broken when you release the mouse, you simply need to add `last_pos = None` under the `elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:` statement.

Answer (score 2):

vgel is right, you need to pass the previous position and the current position to `pygame.draw.line`. You can also calculate the previous position by subtracting the `event.rel` attribute of the event from the `event.pos` attribute.

It's also possible get rid of the `drawing` variable by using the `event.buttons` attribute. If `event.buttons[0]` is `True` then the left mouse button is being pressed.

```
import pygame


def main():
    pygame.init()

    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 800), 0, 32)
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if event.buttons[0]:  # Left mouse button down.
                    last = (event.pos[0]-event.rel[0], event.pos[1]-event.rel[1])
                    pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, last, event.pos, 1)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)  # Limit the frame rate to 30 FPS.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```